# Rolling Standard Deviation in Pandas Returning Zeroes for One Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation, rolling-computation

Has anyone had issues with rolling standard deviations not working on only one column in a pandas dataframe?

I have a dataframe with a datetime index and associated financial data. When I run df.rolling().std() (psuedo code, see actual below), I get correct data for all columns except one. That column returns 0's where there should be standard deviation values. I also get the same error when using .rolling_std() and I get an error when trying to run df.rolling().skew(), all the other columns work and this column gives NaN.

What's throwing me off about this error is that the other columns work correctly and for this column, df.rolling().mean() works. In addition, the column has dtype float64, which shouldn't be a problem. I also checked and don't see missing data. I'm using a rolling window of 30 days and if I try to get the last standard deviation value using series[-30:].std() I get a correct result. So it seems like something specifically about the rolling portion isn't working. I played around with the parameters of .rolling() but couldn't get anything to change.

```
# combine the return, volume and slope data
raw_factor_data = pd.concat([fut_rets, vol_factors, slope_factors], axis=1)

# create new dataframe for each factor type (mean,
# std dev, skew) and combine
mean_vals = raw_factor_data.rolling(window=past, min_periods=past).mean()
mean_vals.columns = [column + '_mean' for column in list(mean_vals)]

std_vals = raw_factor_data.rolling(window=past, min_periods=past).std()
std_vals.columns = [column + '_std' for column in list(std_vals)]

skew_vals = raw_factor_data.rolling(window=past, min_periods=past).skew()
skew_vals.columns = [column + '_skew' for column in list(skew_vals)]

fact_data = pd.concat([mean_vals, std_vals, skew_vals], axis=1)
```

The first line combines three dataframes together. Then I create separate dataframes with rolling mean, std and skew (past = 30), and then combine those into a single dataframe.

The name of the column I'm having trouble with is 'TY1_slope'. So I've run some code as follows to see where there is an error.

```
print raw_factor_data['TY1_slope'][-30:].std()
print raw_factor_data['TY1_slope'][-30:].mean()

print raw_factor_data['TY1_slope'].rolling(window=30, min_periods=30).std()
print raw_factor_data['TY1_slope'].rolling(window=30, min_periods=30).mean()
```

The first two lines of code output a correct standard deviation and mean (.08 and .14). However, the third line of code produces zeroes but the fourth line produces accurate mean values (the final values in those series are 0.0 and .14).

If anyone can help with how to look at the .rolling source code that would be helpful too. I'm new to doing that and tried the following, but just got a few lines that didn't seem very helpful.

```
import inspect
import pandas as pd
print inspect.getsourcelines(pd.rolling_std)
```

Comment: Imagine the ease with which one could debug your code without your data!

Comment: I understand, but I haven't been able to re-create the issue with random data / in a simple example (part of the reason I was asking if someone has seen this before or can give direction on looking at source code). I'm completely willing to send the full code with db it's pulling from if someone is willing to look at it. df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30,5), index=pd.date_range('20170101', periods=30), columns=['ES1_vol', 'TY1_vol', 'JY1_vol', 'EC1_vol', 'YM1_vol']) is the general type of dataframe.

Comment: try doing it on subsets of the column until you can narrow down to some (hopefully small) subset of the data and just show that data.  Seems likely to be data-related in some way.  You could also try calculating std on that column in some other program (excel, r, sas, stata, etc.) to see what happens in other programs

Comment: shot in the dark, but you could try `rolling(30).apply( lambda x: np.std(x,ddof=1) )` in case it's some weird syntax bug with rolling + std

Answer (score 0):

Quoting JohnE's comment since it worked (although still not sure the root cause of the issue). JohnE, feel free to change to an answer and I'll upvote.

> shot in the dark, but you could try rolling(30).apply( lambda x: np.std(x,ddof=1) ) in case it's some weird syntax bug with rolling + std – JohnE